# injectivity of the function $f: \quad \mathbb{R}^2_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \quad : (x,y)\quad \longmapsto \ (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function:

$$f: \quad \mathbb{R}^2_+ \ \longrightarrow \ \mathbb{R}^2  \quad : \quad (x,y) \ \longmapsto \ (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$$

I had to show that this function is injective. According to the exercise, I had to prove the identity:
$$ (\tilde{x}^2 + y^2)(\tilde{y}^2-y^2) = 0 \qquad \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ \  \ \ f(x,y) \ = \ f(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$$

Maybe this this very easy, but I didn't know how to show this, and I didn't know how to establish injectivity by this either. I haven't produced anything fruitful. Could you please help me?

Comment: Is $\;\Bbb R^2_+\;$ the set of elements in the plane with *both* entries positive?

Comment: yes it is, donantonio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x,y)=f(\tilde x, \tilde y)$ then $$(\tilde x^2 + y^2)(\tilde y^2 - y^2) = \tilde x^2\tilde y^2 - y^4 + y^2(\tilde y^2 - \tilde x^2) = x^2y^2 - y^4 + y^2(y^2 - x^2) = 0$$

Also if this is zero then one of the brackets is zero. Then either $\tilde x = y = 0$ or $|\tilde y | = |y|$ and in either case you can work out the rest.

Comment: How can one "work out the rest"?

Comment: @mavavilj We've shown that if $f(x,y) = f(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ then either $\bar{x} = y = 0$ or $|\bar{y}| = |y|$. Remembering we also already know $x,y,\bar{x},\bar{y} > 0$, what can you say about each of these cases immediately? Now use $f(x,y) = f(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ again.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a,b)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)\iff(x,y)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}2+\frac12\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\sqrt{-\frac{a}2+\frac12\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$g:\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}\mid\text{Re }z,\text{Im }z>0\right\} \rightarrow\mathbb{C}$
defined by $z\mapsto z^{2}$ is injective.

So the corresponding $f:\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$
defined by $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\left(x^{2}-y^{2},2xy\right)$
is injective.